# NVDIA driver issue in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lightdm, macbook

I tried install the nvdia driver for ubuntu 17.10, but it was a failure the display was totally black. So I purged the Nvidia drivers and returned back to generic display driver but unfortunately it was not completely reverted back, which causing the following issues

1. Never resume back from suspend mode
2. Display resolution gone back to 1280x800
3. No brightness control
4. No night mode
5. Gama error. etc...
   My display card is 
   02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400M] [10de:0863] (rev b1)
   The xrandr gives the following error

   xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
   Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 800, current 1280 x 800, maximum 1280 x 800
   default connected primary 1280x800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
      1280x800      76.00* 
   Lightdm service status is

   ● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-01-22 18:44:15 IST; 24min ago
    Docs: man:lightdm(1)
   Process: 14037 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-di
   Main PID: 14048 (lightdm)
   Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 33.4M
     CPU: 2min 56.014s
   CGroup: /system.slice/lightdm.service
          ├─14048 /usr/sbin/lightdm
          └─14069 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightd

Jan 22 18:44:16 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14083]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kw
Jan 22 18:44:16 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14083]: PAM adding faulty module: p
Jan 22 18:44:16 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14083]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:se
Jan 22 18:44:20 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14148]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kw
Jan 22 18:44:20 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14148]: PAM adding faulty module: p
Jan 22 18:44:20 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14148]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kw
Jan 22 18:44:20 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14148]: PAM adding faulty module: p
Jan 22 18:44:20 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14148]: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth
Jan 22 18:44:58 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14048]: g_object_unref: assertion '
Jan 22 18:44:58 shameerariff-MacBook lightdm[14148]: pam_unix(lightdm:session):

It seems weired to me. 
I tried restoring using the [Wiki Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:__Need_to_fully_remove_-nvidia_and_reinstall_-nouveau_from_scratch) but still all my efforts are failed.

Comment: GeForce 9400M is legacy hardware currently supported only by Nvidia 340 driver version. I suggest you install that one properly.

Comment: I tried installing from NVIDIA official website and the file name was NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.104.run as well as from the ubuntu repository, but both failed.

Comment: If you used the Nvidia binary you need to run it again with the uninstall option otherwise the leftovers will prevent any further experiments. Likewise, you need to purge the drivers installed with APT in order to start over. Had you from the beginning installed properly - opening Additional drivers, selecting and applying -  nothing of this would be happening.

Comment: now I am getting a new error from nvidia install ie.  X server

Comment: Somehow I managed to install nvidia 340 driver from ubuntu repository and no difference when I run the nvidia-detector it says none. Its surprising me. Probably today was my bad luck

Comment: Somehow I managed to revert back to generic nouveau