# No brightness control 18.04 LTS: /sys/class/backlight is empty

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, brightness, backlight

I know this issue had been addressed in the past (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003330/nothing-in-the-sys-class-backlight-and-i-cant-control-the-brightness-of-disp), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054823/backlight-broken-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-18-04), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036041/brightness-buttons-not-working-in-18-04), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/8o6d0d/no_brightness_control_for_intel_graphics_in_a/), [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1775065), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998662/nvdia-driver-issue-in-ubuntu-17-10) and more), but none were actually given a definite answer.

To begin, I'm using a NVDIA GTX1080 Max-Q graphic card. Installed driver 390 (Can't seems to switch to 396, it automatically rolled back to 390 when I select in 'Additional Drivers'). And the folder `/sys/class/backlight` is empty, as mentioned.

Next, I try to disable Wayland in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and that resulted with me greeted by black screen after login. Can't seems to enter grub mode by pressing Alt+Ctrl+F1. Referred answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011557/851663). Reinstalled Ubuntu many times just to be sure about this.

Then, tried the method as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043598/851663) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035527/851663). Still didn't fix it.

Temporarily I'm using the [bash script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013767/851663) to adjust the brightness, but it would jump to maximum again if a prompt pop up, like Authentication or copying files.

Any actual way to fix this once and for all?

Answer (score 9):

`xbacklight` does not work for you, right?

In my case a workaround is use the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia.NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler=1"
```

in the `/etc/default/grub` file.
The problem is explained [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025559/linux/solus-nvidia-gtx-1070-brightness-control-not-working/post/5216392/)

Comment: worked for nvidia 1070 msi laptop

Comment: Not work on Ubuntu 18.04 install at Razer Studio Nvidia RTX 5000

Comment: Not working on Kali linux : HP Spectre x360 1650 ti NVIDIA 4gb

Comment: not working on HP with Geforce 1650, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did not work on an Asus G752VS with a GTX 1070 under Ubuntu 20.04. Pretty different from the usual answers on this topic though! A shame it's still a pain to get brightness working after 16 years of using Ubuntu :(

Comment: Did not work for Macbook with GT 610M with debian 11.

Answer (score 4):

For me [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/function-brightness-keys-doesnt-works-under-ubuntu-18-04-nvidia-gt755m/62862/2) worked on my old laptop with NVIDIA GeForce 410M graphics card, Intel Core i3.

> I've tried all of those too and found this one working:
> you make a file into this folder `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`
> the file name should be this: `cat 80-nvidia.conf`
>
> so this should be like : `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ cat 80-nvidia.conf`
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
> Identifier "Device0"
> Driver "nvidia"
> VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
> BoardName "NVS 3100M"
> Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
> EndSection
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with GeForce 9400 and NVIDIA 340. I solved it using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135561/1072890):

> For me [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135561/1072890) worked on my old laptop with NVIDIA GeForce 410M
> graphics card, Intel Core i3.
>
> > I've tried all of those too and found this one working:
> > you make a file into this folder `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`
> > the file name should be this: `cat 80-nvidia.conf`
> >
> > so this should be like : `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ cat 80-nvidia.conf`
> >
> > ```
> > Section "Device"
> > Identifier "Device0"
> > Driver "nvidia"
> > VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
> > BoardName "NVS 3100M"
> > Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
> > EndSection
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

OK I tested it out with a few different versions.  This is with the nvidia "legacy" 340.107 drivers.  with my macbook late 2009 (nvidia) I got empty /sys/class/backlight in every version of Ubuntu I tried.  No amount of tinkering with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT helped.  Maybe with newer nvidia cards that don't require the "legacy" old drivers it might be different.

And xbacklight doesn't work either, until you add a device file like Satya's answer to this question mentioned.  Then after exiting and logging in again, xbacklight works (ex: `xbacklight -set 60).  But not the hotkeys and not the GUI dragger.

There's a library called "nvidiabl" that's supposed to be some fake software drivers to populate /sys/class/backlight when the nvidia ones don't.  It didn't compile for me on 18.04 so no go there.

Based on a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-384/+bug/1720438) that ascribed it to a gnome bug "not being able to use xbacklight", tried it with 18.04 with "kde plasma" and unity instead.  With both of them the backlight keys work (notwithstanding empty /sys/class/backlight).  So guessing it's a thing gnome could work around?

Tested it out using 19.04 and still needed the .conf file added, and /sys/class/backlight is still empty.  But now it works natively (gnome), no manual hotkeys needed to call out to xbacklight, woot!  Added bonus: gnome is way more cpu efficient in 19.04 than 18.04 so even using nouveau things are snappier, woot (also things are snappier on 18.04 with KDE FWIW).

So overall fix: update to 19.04 and create new conf.d [file](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135561/20972)

Comment: downvoters please leave comments, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If /sys/class/backlight/ is empty it means your graphic card driver is not installed. That happens due to a kernel update which does not provide a driver for your GPU.

Issue:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
```

to find out what is your graphic card. For example mine is "GP106BM [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 6GB]" which is an Nvidia graphic card.

Then for automatic install of Nvidia driver using PPA repository issue:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed Satya;s advice but it didn't work for me.

I have also created another config file as per [Brightness problem - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221452#6) but it didn't help either.

Finally I followed Ducky's answer as described in [Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts) and changed grub a bit.

Open the file ***/etc/default/grub*** using gedit or any other text editor. Find below line.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change above line to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Finally my function keys became operative.

Comment: Now you've created an account here, you'll need to follow the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts to connect this answer to it.

Comment: This does not work in Kali Linux NVIDIA 1650 ti