# Brightness keyboard shortcut not working on Ubuntu 20.04 with GeForce MX230

Tags: nvidia, shortcut-keys, 20.04, brightness

I have a i7 10th with a MX230 GeForce. I have installed only Ubuntu 20.04. During Ubuntu's installation, I [did this](https://gist.github.com/bitsurgeon/b0f4440984c9e60dcd8fe8bbc346c029#secure-boot) to install NVIDIA drivers. The current configuration is:

[image: 2]

I can play video games and so on, but every time I try to use the brightness keyboard shortcuts, my entire UI is frozen for a little while(10s). Decreasing the brightness works fine (besides the 10s UI freeze), but trying to increase it freezes it longer than 10s and after it unfreezes, it behaves as nothing happened. I cannot fail any new attempt to solve this since I have important data into this machine. I've found these options:

- [Brightness problem Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034305/brightness-problem-ubuntu-18-04-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [No brightness control 18.04 LTS: /sys/class/backlight is empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057783/no-brightness-control-18-04-lts-sys-class-backlight-is-empty?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solus-nvidia-gtx-1070-brightness-control-not-working/54472
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/function-brightness-keys-doesnt-works-under-ubuntu-18-04-nvidia-gt755m/62862
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007765
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181534&p=12819813#post12819813

But none of them are specific to Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia MX230. Before executing each one of them as 'try and error', is there any specific instruction for this specific setup?

Comment: ps: by settings > power > screen brightness slider everything works fine

Comment: ps2: I also tried Ubuntu 18.04, had the same behavior. This seems to be Ubuntu version agnostic

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 21.04 with 465.19.01 driver.

Unfortunately, the native laptop controls can be used only across nouveau driver.

After several workarounds the following instructions works for me:

```
sudo apt install brightnessctl
```

This command only works as root. You can add your user to a group called video:

```
sudo gpasswd -a <user_name> video
```

After logout/login or reboot, copy and save this script:

```bsh
 #!/bin/bash

#Selected option + or -
COMMAND=$1

# Current brightness value
CURRENT_VALUE=$(brightnessctl g)

# Max supported brightness value
MAX_VALUE=$(brightnessctl m)

# Min valid brightness percent
MIN_BRIGHTNESS=$(($MAX_VALUE*5/100))

# Value used to increase or decrease brightness when - or + is passed as argument
BIAS="5%"

# Increase laptop screen brightness according to $BIAS
if [ "$COMMAND" == "+" ]; then
    brightnessctl -s -q s +$BIAS
fi

# Decrease laptop screen brightness according to $BIAS
if [ "$COMMAND" == "-" ]; then
  # Limit minimum brightness to avoid black screen
    if [ $CURRENT_VALUE -gt $MIN_BRIGHTNESS ]; then
        brightnessctl -s -q s $BIAS-
    fi
fi
```

After saving this script, you can map your keyboard shortcut under **Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts** like this:

[decrease brightness sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RymN.png)
[increase brightness sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av9Ey.png)

Enjoy